# HTML Posting An Array Only Posting First Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Certificate Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
    #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #main .my-form form .text-box .add-box strong {
      font-size: 36px;
    }
-->
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1 align="center">Certificate Generator</h1>
    <div class="type">
    <form name="class" action="generate.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="i">IL<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="u">UT</br> 
  </div>
    <div class="my-form">
        <form action ="generate.php"role="form" method="post">
             <label for="text">Date <span class="box-number"</span></label>
             <input type="text" name="date" /></p>
            <p class="text-box"> 
                <label for="box1">Student <span class="box-number">1</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="students[]" value="" id="box1" />
                <a class="add-box" href="#"><strong>Add More Students</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Generate Certificates" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
        if( 250 < n ) {
            alert('Maximum Amount of Students');
            return false;
        }
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Student <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="students[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
        $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit submit, the php only gets the first value of the array

```
$students = ($_POST["students"]);
```

this is my php for that form, I don't know why it is only returning the first value of the array, this is my first time using forms with JavaScript so it might just be a simple error, I'm not sure

Comment: your additional inputs appear? named correctly (view generated source) ?

Comment: use a dom inspector to view the html you're generating/inserting, make sure it's coming out properly. "view source" generally won't do, because that's usually the source as it was grabbed from the server, BEFORE any dom modifying code was executed (e.g. your javascript).

Comment: every one should have the web devloper add on with its "view generated source"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the error. I have this working. You are not adding the new elements inside of your form. I rearranged the HTML as the following.

```
<form name="class" action="generate.php" method="post">
<div id="main">
<h1 align="center">Certificate Generator</h1>
<div class="type">
  <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="i">IL<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="u">UT</br>
</div>
<div class="my-form">
<form action ="generate.php"role="form" method="post">
  <label for="text">Date <span class="box-number"</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="date" />
  </p>
  <p class="text-box">
    <label for="box1">Student <span class="box-number">1</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="students[]" value="" id="box1" />
    <a class="add-box" href="#"><strong>Add More Students</strong></a> </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Certificates" />
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Just to clarify, I moved the opening tag of the form outside of your "main" div, and then I closed the form after the "main" div's closing tag. No other changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
  <form name="class" action="generate.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="i">IL<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="class" value="u">UT</br>
</div>
<div class="my-form">
  <form action ="generate.php"role="form" method="post">
```

You are closing your form prematurely because of the closing `</div>` and then opening a new form.

Your html is invalid and the browser tries to make sense of it, causing your `students[]` elements to be outside of your form so they never get posted.

The results may vary per browser (tested in Firefox), but validating your html should solve your problem.